# Change size of modal sheet from half to full animated in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

I would like a certain view to start as a half-screen sheet, but when it's done with some loading, it should transform into a full-screen sheet.

So in UIKit my solution would be that:

```
let vc = UIViewController()
vc.view.backgroundColor = .red
vc.sheetPresentationController?.detents = [.medium(), .large()]
self.present(vc, animated: true)

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(1)) {
    vc.sheetPresentationController?.animateChanges {
        vc.sheetPresentationController?.selectedDetentIdentifier = .large
    }
}
```

That works fine in UIKit... but is this also somehow possible in SwiftUI?

Something similar in SwiftUI could look like the following:

```
    struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showSheet = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            showSheet = true
        } label: {
            Text("Show-Sheet")
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet, content: {
            SheetView()
        })
    }
}

struct SheetView: View {
    @State var showFullSheet = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            withAnimation {
                showFullSheet.toggle()
            }
        } label: {
            Text("Toggle")
        }
        .presentationDetents(showFullSheet ? [.large] : [.medium, .large])
    }
}
```

This basically works, but the problem is that the transition between half and full is NOT animated. I'd need it animated though. Is this somehow solvable in SwiftUI?
Cause I guess wrapping my presented view in a UIViewController that then hosts my existing SwiftUI View would not be an option, as the presentation part would still be done by swift-ui, right?

Comment: Did you check documentation?
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/presentationdetents(_:selection:)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all use `selection` binding of [`presentationDetents(_:selection:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/presentationdetents(_:selection:))
to keep track of your `selectedDetent` state. The reason you are facing this animation issue is when you set `sheet` to `large` you are setting allow detents set only with `[.large]` so it's not animating and directly jumping to large. To overcome this issue I have added `@State` property to update allow detents with `presentationDetents` modifier. Now if you update `detents` `set` as soon as you update your `selectedDetent` state then also it won't show animation, so to fix this issue I have added a one-second delay to update `detents` and this will fix your animation issue.

```
struct SheetView: View {
    @State var selectedDetent: PresentationDetent = .medium
    
    @State var detents: Set<PresentationDetent> = [.large, .medium]
    
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            selectedDetent = selectedDetent == .large ? .medium : .large
        } label: {
            Text("Toggle")
        }
        .presentationDetents(detents, selection: $selectedDetent)
        .onChange(of: selectedDetent) { newValue in
            if newValue == .large {
                updateDetentsWithDelay()
            } else {
                detents = [.large, .medium]
            }
        }
    }
    
    func updateDetentsWithDelay() {
        Task {
            //(1 second = 1_000_000_000 nanoseconds)
            try? await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 100_000_000)
            guard selectedDetent == .large else { return }
            detents = [.large]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It indeed animates down. Nice! But would it also be possible to animate it up. So from `.medium` -> `.large` with an animation? Cause that's what I'd need. Start in medium and go to large, but nicely animated.

Comment: Sorry... did't check on the weekend! Yes... it works! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Could it just be that you're missing `withAnimation` from your `showSheet = true`

Comment: Sheet by default present with animation, so no need to add `withAnimation` to present sheet

Comment: As Nirav mentionened it animated even without. But I would even have had it in a `withAnimation` closure.